# Pages that don't look like blog posts?

Tags: pages, customization

I 've been scouting around for answers on creating static pages (that means NO BLOG POSTS of any kind) on pages where you don't want ANYTHING that looks blog related, (posts, leave a comment, date created, etc.) Think of pages like Contact Us, About Us, Bio, etc.

The closest thing I could find is changing your homepage to static in the Reading Settings (and even that didn't do the trick!)

I don't know if this matters, but I'm using [Son of Blue theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/son-of-blue). I don't understand much about coding, so if there is a line of code that needs to be changed/updated, please be very specific..

Answer (score 1):

Try searching the [WPORG Theme Repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) for a Theme updated sometime since Fall 2010 or so. The [Theme Review Guidelines](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review) require that Pages not display time-related content (such as Post Date/Time stamp), and that Pages not display "comments are closed" type messages on Pages with comments disabled.

The Son of Blue Theme was last updated in May 2010, which means that it may not meet the current Theme Review Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want it to look "bloggy"?

I'd suggest just commenting out the comments tag in single.php.

In your single.php file, find where it says:

```
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

And change it to:

```
<?php // comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

That could be a start and anytime you want your comments back just delete those two forward slashes.

Comment: The `single.php` template file is not used for *static Pages*. If the OP wants to go the route of updating his existing Theme, the template file to modify is `page.php`.

Comment: Yes, also in page.php.  But he's talking about the homepage suggesting that he needs all his posts to look like pages. Unless he's trying to use just pages and not posts.

Comment: "*Unless he's trying to use just pages and not posts.*" That is the impression I get from the OP: the site will consist *only* of static Pages, and no blog Posts.

Comment: thanks for your responses guys!  Yes Chip you are correct, I'm trying to create a site using only static pages (except maybe some widgets).

Jimmy, I tried the forward slashes in the single.php template but it didn't do anything.  

I also tried removed the entire "post" div class from page.php, but my site disappeared completely!  

hmm.. seems there would be a standard button somewhere for turning off blogs on a page.. isn't this a common request??

Thanks again!